# Insert nested json into cassandra

Tags: python, cassandra

Im trying to insert this nested object into cassandra database, but cannot figure out how to design the table for this. I want all the data from this object to be stored in cassandra.

Below I pasted the json im trying to insert.

Any suggestions?

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "resultType": "vector",
    "result": [
      {
        "metric": {
          "__name__": "up",
          "env": "demosite",
          "instance": "localhost:9100",
          "job": "node"
        },
        "value": [
          1553849977.349,
          "1"
        ]
      },
      {
        "metric": {
          "__name__": "up",
          "instance": "ub-lab-server:9090",
          "job": "prometheus"
        },
        "value": [
          1553849977.349,
          "1"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this.

If your use case is just to store the JSON as a string , just serialize the whole JSON as a blob into a single column
Create a table as :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table(
  ID <text/bigint>
  DATA text,
  CREATEDATE timestamp
)
```

If you want to represent all the nested attributes as separate columns , you will have start from bottom up.
i.e first create [User Defined Types](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCreateUDT.html) for each nested field.
In reference to your json , an example would be :

```
CREATE TYPE metric (
      name text,
      env text,
      instance text,
      job text
);

CREATE TYPE value(
      field1 text,
      field2 text
);
```

Once you have the bas UDTs created , start with creating Composite UDTs , referencing base UDTs :

```
CREATE TYPE result(
  metric metric,
  value value,
);

CREATE TYPE data(
  resultType text,
  result set<result>,
);
```

And then finally bootstrap your table as following :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table (
  ID <text/bigint>
  status data
)
```

Be careful in deciding on your primary/partition keys based on your querying and storage
usecases.